# K2 Export Project rather than item

Tags: c#, console, export, k2

I am trying to find out a way to export all items in a project at once programmatically through a console application. Exporting all items in a project is possible through K2 Studio, but I cant seem to find a way to do it in C#. There is only a way to do each item one at a time which is far too slow to compile and export. Also when attempting to run the code on this line for example:

```
 k2process.export(myservername, ref results);
```

This line of code always hangs or stops working. Not too sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it cannot be done.